# Is there benefit in listing fewer degree options in MS application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, application

When applying to university one can choose multiple degree programmes he/she wish to apply. Usually you also list them according to your priority. For example application can be targeted to:

1. MS in Physics
2. MS in Mathematics
3. MS in Computer Science

But does this makes an impression for admission board that person is not really knows what he wants to study? Is this somehow beneficial if for example I would state just one option for MS in Physics and nothing else?
For me personally it makes more sense to state just one degree programme in my application, because I would not be really satisfied if I would be "forced" to continue my study in the field I am not so interested compared to my number 1 priority.
On the other hand if I do so then I would basically make my chance to get accepted 3 times less, and that baffles me. But again if I not get accepted then I can wait one year and try again with better education and recognition.

Comment: Usually you can apply to a specific MS in a department of a university. The 1 - 3 options are completly diferent fields of science.

Comment: What kind of university is this?  At my university one normally just applies to one department (though through a general university college).  I believe this is standard for research universities in the US.

Comment: @Christos, this is within one faculty(Faculty of Science). The fields are not completely different, for example particle physics, mathematical physics and data analysis is available, so you can do quite similar research, just from different angles. So the department is same one(this is by the way quite usual for EU universities).

Comment: @Kimball, this is usual practice in EU universities to file multiple applications "just because you can". In my particular case it is Finland, but this shouldn't matter, question is whether this is considered to be unprofessional and can harm your admission chance or is it OK.

Comment: Also I want to add that it is also possible to apply for example to physics department AND for business management at the same time, so yeah, this is quite weird(though I don't think many people do that kind of thing). It is nice for university to allow this, but I doubt admission board will look at such applicant and say "oh, this guy knows what he is doing!"